# Drush not installing correctly

Tags: drush, composer

I'm attempting to install Drush on a new system OSX 10.10.4.

The process is no longer the simple one it used to be :(

I've complied with the requirement to install via Composer (that was not small feat either), and finally have Drush installed.

However, executing Drush results in the following:

```
which drush
env: sh\r: No such file or directory
```

I've seen issues logged similar to this with scripts that had spurious LF/CR. I haven't written any scripts. No idea where this is coming from.

Solutions I've tried include using Composer to uninstall the Drush and install 6. Process appears to work, but results the same when attempting to run Drush.

Answer (score -1):

The error message suggests that the script you're invoking has embedded **\r** characters, which in turn suggests that it has Window-style **\r** line endings.

Try to install from other source or something

Comment: Right, I mentioned that in the problem description, still, what script could I possibly be invoking? 
It is hard to believe that this process, that is documented in several places would have that kind of bug... and if it did, I wouldn't be the first to encounter it.  Very strange!